# singleInstance Activity launched twice intermittently on Android 8 Oreo

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I have an Activity that is launchMode=singleInstance. On Android 8 Oreo, about 30% of the time I get 2 separate launches of the Activity.  They are different Object instances and the first does not get an onNewIntent() when the second is launched.

Also, if I query the ActivityManager from the second launched activity, the first is not reported.

I do start the activity from a background service as there is some push messaging involved.

I also log to ensure there is only one context.startActivity() happening.

In logcat, when this happens I see the following warning

```
10-27 18:38:49.153 379-3304/? W/ActivityManager: Activity ActivityRecord{a21333f u0 my.package.name/my.package.name.MyActivity t1409} being launched, but already in LRU list
```

This is Android O specific and everything works on previous versions.

Any help appreciated, been banging my head against the wall on this for awhile... if there is a known Android Bug for this please let me know! I didn't find anything

Answer (score 0):

In the end I couldn't prevent the second Activity from launching. I had to be able to tolerate having the Activity launched twice.

The first Activity gets onCreate() to onResume() then it's gone. Like really gone without even an onPause().

The second Activity gets the onCreate() just after the first's onResume(). That second Activity goes through the normal lifecycles and is just fine.

The Android OS must realize that it shouldn't have launched the second instance, so it hard kills the first instance... weird